# Static files in Django not being served

Tags: python, django

I have been just experimenting lately with Django 1.8, and I can't understand why my static files are not being served through my page with the development server. I am able to serve the static files fine with this URL inside URL patterns :

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', startpage),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

But when I include another URL such as:

```
url(r'^start/', startpage),
```

It doesn't display the static content as the other URL even though both URL's call the same startpage. Is it something to do with my settings.py? Thank you. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: please paste your whole urls.py and your settings.STATIC_ROOT and settings.STATIC_URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my files were in the wrong directory, problem was fixed a while ago.